# Обработка массива php

Tags: массивы, php, база-данных

Здравствуйте.
Извиняюсь за нескромный вопрос, но вот к вечеру уже не могу додумать каким образом мне произвести выборку из базы либо просто операцию над полученным массивом.

Допустим есть таблица с 3 столбцами

user_id | date | clicks

user_id - просто int
date - имеет формат 31.01.2011
clicks - тоже int

Нужно отсеять те user_id у которых количество clicks было на нуле либо 2 дня единовременно, либо 3 в совокупности за месяц.

Подскажите хотя бы примерное условие, буду очень благодарен!

Comment: Как это понять?

     каким образом мне произвести выборку из базы либо просто   
     операцию над полученным массивом

Comment: Что значит "2 дня единовременно". И что значит "3 в совокупности за месяц" (т.е. месяц январь, февраль и т.д)? Если за такой месяц, то за какой -- за любой? за текущий? Тип поля 'date'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первая выборка - это выборка пар последовательных дат, в которых клики нулевые:

```
SELECT t1.user_id
FROM tab t1, tab t2
WHERE 
  t1.dat=date_add(t2.dat,INTERVAL 1 DAY)
  AND t1.dat BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('01.01.2012','%d.%m.%Y') and STR_TO_DATE('30.01.2012','%d.%m.%Y')
  AND t1.user_id=t2.user_id
  AND t1.clicks = 0
  AND t2.clicks = 0
GROUP BY t1.user_id
```

Вторая выборка на количество с нулями, которых 3 и больше:

```
SELECT t3.user_id
FROM tab t3
WHERE
  t3.clicks=0
  AND t3.dat BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('01.01.2012','%d.%m.%Y') and STR_TO_DATE('31.01.2012','%d.%m.%Y')
GROUP BY t3.user_id
HAVING count(t3.user_id)>=3
```

Дальше эти запросы можно объединить через union.

Это по январю '12. Если надо интервалами, смысл остается тот же, просто в выборках выводить месяц даты, и группировать по нему.

Answer (score 0):

Может быть так...

```
SELECT * FROM table t
 WHERE t.clicks = 0
   AND t.clicks < 3
   AND t.date BETWEEN TO_DATE('01.01.2012','DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('01.02.2012','DD/MM/YYYY')
```